# Facebook Login not working properly (Parse)

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform

In my app, I have an activity that handles the Facebook sign in and sign up. When I click my "Sign in with Facebook" button, I execute this code, as written the [Parse docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers):

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d(APPTAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                Log.d(APPTAG, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            } else {
                Log.d(APPTAG, "User logged in through Facebook!");
            }
        }
});
```

This is supposed to handle new and existing users.

I also have this method in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In my `Application` class, I set up Parse and ParseFacebookUtils properly:

```
Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_app_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
```

I also have the Facebook App installed on my device.

The problem I have is that when I call `ParseFacebookUtils.logIn()`, it always returns a ParseUser that's not new or null, but that is effectivly empty. It has no `objectId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, etc. The `ParseException` also is always null.

I'm also not sure why the `ParseUser` in the `done` callback has a false value for `user.isNew()` because there aren't any users in my `_User` table. Usually, the Facebook sign in should create a new `ParseUser` if one doesn't already exist.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing my app but that didn't work. Even If I clear every table, in the Data Browser, clear my cache, and get a completely fresh install of my app, It never shows that the user is new.

I found a [similar post on the Parse help forum](https://parse.com/questions/facebook-login-not-creating-a-new-parseuser), but there were no answers.

In my `AndroidManifest`, I have this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

<activity
    android:name=".activities.SignUpOrLogInActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" />
```

The `SignUpOrLogInActivity` is where I have my "Sign in with Facebook" button.

In my log, I sometimes see this warning:

```
Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token.
```

I then tried to log the Facebook application Id and access token like this:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().getApplicationId()
```

and

```
ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().getAccessToken()
```

The Facebook app id is correct and the session token printed some string that looked correct.

I have Parse Version: **1.5.1** and Facebook SDK version **3.14.1**.

**Edit:**

I looked in my Cloud Code log and found this error:

```
I2014-08-17T18:12:35.381Z] v314: before_save triggered for _User
  Input: {"original":null,"update":{"username":"n7Tr5fvBGumtCv2MxwY8V3PHF","authData":{"facebook":{"id":"[my_fb_id]","access_token":"CAAEK5cQebpEBAHz2vgqtJ3ADuoAIWJb6pos1ykobZCi4PjwsZAVLuN14EiOTJJLdhR97iiwSefSU5nvlVSq5ZBCiopyTycpsQDw5jM7rnBZBUrWvrbPcTIAmp8JomPAXmTrUok93BDhdireVrtxED86ziaxm29nUCuhb2PHMQZAWGNTDyKkxdeUthsFzC7F4WmmKCQUJpZAwYlebHWOfI9y02B0O8DNSZARTLjfpmZCvXQZDZD","expiration_date":"2014-10-16T16:11:57.000Z"}}}}
  Result: Invalid email.
```

Comment: If you do not really need to have this made your way, maybe you could try native facebook login button? [Facebook login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a before save function for the Parse User class like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    var user = request.object;
    if (!/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/.test(user.get("email"))) {
        response.error("Invalid email.");
    } else if (!user.get("email")) {
        response.error("Every user must have an email address.");
    } else {
        response.success();
    }
});
```

I got rid of this to fix the issue.