# Facebook login with Parse always returns false in user.isNew() Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have an issue with Facebook login in Android using Parse.
Everything is working fine but I always get User logged in through Facebook.

I found a guy with the same problem here [Facebook Login not working properly (Parse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334873/facebook-login-not-working-properly-parse) but his answer doesnt work for me.

```
        List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email");
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, getActivity(), new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d("WelcomeMainFragment",
                            "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");

                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d("WelcomeMainFragment",
                            "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");


                } else {
                    Log.d("WelcomeMainFragment",
                            "User logged in through Facebook!");
                }
            }
        });
```

`user.isNew()` always returns false! even with new facebooks accounts in my app.
I need to have working isNew() method to be able to create parse users for first time in that block of code.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found what the problem was.
Basically I had two problems:

1. I wasn't getting the key hash properly.

> keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore
>   YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Doing above I was getting the wrong key hash. So I encourage you to get it with this piece of code:

> ```
> try {
>     PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
>             "your.package.name", 
>             PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
>     for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
>         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
>         md.update(signature.toByteArray());
>         Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
>         }
> } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
> } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
> }
> ```

You have to execute it in debug and production to get both keys.

2. The most important problem was that I had to allow Facebook authentication on Parse and include the Facebook app id and app secret. You can do that going to Settings > Authentication > Facebook.

I hope that can help someone.