# Parse - isNew() always returns false when logging in with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

When attempting to login and signup through Facebook, the method `isNew()` somehow always returns **false**, even if the **"_User"** table is empty or if the user is logging in for the first time (signing up).

According to the docs:

> isNew(): Indicates whether this ParseUser was created during this session through a call to ParseUser.signUp() or by logging in with a linked service such as Facebook.

Here's the code:

```
private void loginWithFacebook() {
    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground((Activity) getContext(), null, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            if (user != null) {
                if (user.isNew()) {
                    onLoginListener.onSignupWithFacebook();
                } else {
                    onLoginListener.onLoginWithFacebook();
                }
            } else if (e != null) {
                handleException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Other people have come across similar problems and fixed it, but the solutions they've come up with don't apply to my case:

[Facebook login with Parse always returns false in user.isNew() Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720893/facebook-login-with-parse-always-returns-false-in-user-isnew-android)

[Facebook Login not working properly (Parse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334873/facebook-login-not-working-properly-parse)

[User.isNew() returns false when it should return true](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/XsaPYr56Vuw)

Apart from that, everything else seems to be working fine. The user data is created and stored on the table just like it normally should. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi I have the same issue and I want to know if you find any convenient solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

remove `enableAutomaticUser()` if you have written in `Application` or `BaseActivity` class

docs says that this method will `Enables automatic creation of anonymous users.`

**remove except this three and try may help you.!!**

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
Parse.initialize(this,getString(R.string.parse_app_id),getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
```